# How to upload big files AJAX + Web.py

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, web.py

I'm using a web.py app as a server and JQuery in the client. A part of the app need to upload files, and i get it working with this in the client:

```
$('#filesend').click( function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open( 'PUT', '/ajax/file', true );

    var form = $('#fileform')[0];
    var fd = new FormData( form );
    xhr.send( fd );
});
```

And with this code in the server:

```
def PUT( self ):
    try:
        x = web.input(myfile={})
        filename = data.getUserFilename( session.user, x['myfile'].filename )
        data.saveFile( filename, x['myfile'].file )
    except:
            print sys.exc_info()
            web.debug( "can't save file" )

    return "OK"
```

But, when I use a file > 2GBs aprox. I'm getting an error in the web.input method.

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 1008, in readline
    bline = buf.readline(size)
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
```

I'm able to check in the client when the file is to big to upload with the current method but, What can be used to upload files bigger than 2GBs?

Comment: have you solved this yet?

Comment: I do think that you should change a configuration somewhere that limits the max file size.

Comment: @AlexTwain I solved it splitting the file in chunks with <2GB size.

Comment: but how to do this? Can you post an answer here with your approach please?

Comment: http://webpy.org/cookbook/limiting_upload_size

Comment: @AlexTwain I post the solution I used. I test also changing cgi.maxlen but it don't solve the problem. I think the problem is from internal allocation limits on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem slicing the file in chunks and sending them to the server one one at a time.

First, we create a variable that contains the information about the file and the transmission process, and we send a message to the server to start:

```
function sendBigFile(){
    var input = $('#filesel')[0]
    var file = input.files[0]
    var descriptor = {
        sended: 0,
        file: file,
        filename: file.name,
        total: file.size,
        chunkSize: 5*1024*1024,
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function( e ){
        if( 4 == this.readyState ){
            sendBigFilePart( descriptor )
        }
    };

    xhr.open( 'PUT', '/web/ajax/filepart', true )

    var fd = new FormData()
    fd.append( 'status', 'start' )
    fd.append( 'myfilename', descriptor.filename )
    xhr.send( fd )
}
```

Then each part of the file is sended with:

```
function sendBigFilePart( desc ){
    if( desc.sended >= desc.total ){
        // assert desc.sended == desc.total ??
        sendBigFileEnd( desc )
    }else{
        var chunk = Math.min( desc.total - desc.sended, desc.chunkSize )
        var current = desc.sended
        var blob = desc.file.slice( current, current + chunk )

        desc.sended = desc.sended + chunk

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function( e ){
            if( 4 == this.readyState ){
                sendBigFilePart( desc )
            }
        };

        xhr.open( 'PUT', '/web/ajax/filepart', true );

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append( 'myfile', blob )
        fd.append( 'status', 'part' )
        fd.append( 'myfilename', desc.filename )
        xhr.send( fd );
    }
}
```

Last, we send a final message to mark the end of transmission:

```
function sendBigFileEnd( desc ){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open( 'PUT', '/web/ajax/filepart', true )

    var fd = new FormData()
    fd.append( 'status', 'end' )
    fd.append( 'myfilename', desc.filename )
    xhr.send( fd )
}
```